# TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function in bootstrap typeahead plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on autocomplete search with typeahead plugin version 3.1.1. I used php, mysql, ajax and js/jquery. 
When i used mysqli, it display perfectly when typing in search box but the problem is when i use PDO, it gives me an error called

"TypeError: b.toLowerCase is not a function".

The problem is not PDO, i think the typeahead plugin.
If someone faced problem or someone has a solution, please help me to solve it.

The code is:
test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#search').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get('../../xdocs-admin/test/fetch.php', {query: 
 query}, function (data) {

            data= $.parseJSON(data);
            return process(data);
          });
      }

  });

});
```

php code, fetch.php:

```
$host = "mysql";
$username = "root";
$port = 3306;
$db = "xpans_plugs";
$password = "passroot";


  try {
     $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db; port=$port", 
  $username, $password);
     $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
     PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "The connection is failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM search_test";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();


    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();


   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['title'];
    }




     echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: remove `while()` code from php file  and then try

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh, no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After:-

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Do:-

```
$data = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $data[] = $row['title'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

And check

Comment: Alive to Die, It works! Thanks bro ... I think you will help me something further; that is, I fetch my data from the db and display in search box when i type a letter , however how can load it the one that i am targeted?

Comment: Alive to Die--Anant singh I already did... can you help me what i already asked you?

Comment: @amiega  `however how can load it the one that i am targeted?`-> where? Try to ask a new question regarding this by adding your HTML part too and what you tried so far. You will get answer for-sure